# Tikz Nested block diagram with boxed text inside other blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, block

I'd like to create a figure that has a series of nested blocks with text inside.

I'd like 4 blocks like: `[block1]->[block2]->[block3]<-[block4]`
Where blocks look (below), can anyone suggest for me a better approach?:

[image]

Below is my current code,

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,scopes,positioning,arrows,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [mynode/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center, 
            inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=3mm, rounded corners},
    -latex,     
    ]

    % nodes
    % \node[mynode, label={[name=lab]Camera \& Infrared Sensor}] (inner1);
    \node[mynode, label={[name=lab]Camera \& Infrared Sensor}] (inner1) {Time Synchronization};
    \node[mynode, below=12mm of inner1] (justbelow) {Resampling};
    \node[fit={(lab) (justbelow)  (inner1)}, draw] (outer2) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another option is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1cm,
block/.style = {draw, text width=21mm, align=center, rounded corners}
                ]
\node [block] (a) {Time Synch};
\node [block] (b) [below=of a] {Resampling};
% 
\node [block] (c) [right=of a] {Background modeling};
\node [block] (d) [below=of c] {Estimate Sensor Pixel Threshold};
\node [block] (e) [below=of d] {Estimate Overlap Sensor Parameters: Size and Position};
% 
\node [block] (c3a) [right=of c]  {Determine Foreground};
\node [block] (c3b) [below=of c3a] {Create Obfuscated Image};
\node [block] (c3c) [below=of c3b] {Overlap Foreground of Obfuscated Image};
% 
\node [block] (c4a) [right=of c3a]  {Blur};
\node [block] (c4b) [below=of c4a] {Edge};
\node [block] (c4c) [below=of c4b] {Masked};
%
\node[fit={(a) (b)}, draw] (outer1) {};
\node[fit={(c) (d)  (e)}, draw] (outer2) {};
\node[fit={(c3a) (c3b)  (c3c)}, draw] (outer3) {};
\node[fit={(c4a) (c4b)  (c4c)}, draw] (outer4) {};

\path[->]   (outer1) edge (outer2) 
            (outer2) edge (outer3)
            (outer4) edge (outer3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is based on the code that came with your original question. You may understand that I am not redoing this based on the code that you submitted just now.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center,
            text width=4cm,fill=white,
            inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=3mm, rounded corners},
            my arrow/.style={single arrow, draw,minimum height=1.1cm},
rotate border/.style={shape border uses incircle, shape border rotate=#1},
            font=\sffamily]
    \node[mynode, label={[name=lab]Camera \& Infrared Sensor}] (inner1) {Time Synchronization};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of inner1] (justbelow1) {Resampling};
    %
    \node[right=1.5cm of inner1, mynode, label={[name=cal]Calibration \& alignment}] (inner2) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of inner2] (justbelow2) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow2] (justbelow2b) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow2b] (justbelow2c) {};
    %
    \node[right=1.5cm of inner2, mynode, label={[name=img]Create obfuscated
    images}] (inner3) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of inner3] (justbelow3) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow3] (justbelow3b) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow3b] (justbelow3c) {};
    %
    \node[right=1.5cm of inner3, mynode, label={[name=tech]Obfuscation
    techniques}] (inner4) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of inner4] (justbelow4) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow4] (justbelow4b) {};
    \node[mynode, below=2mm of justbelow4b] (justbelow4c) {};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit={(lab) (inner1) (justbelow4c.south-|inner1.south)}, draw,fill=red!20] (outer1) {};
    \node[fit={(cal) (inner2) (justbelow2c)}, draw,fill=red!20] (outer2) {};
    \node[fit={(img) (inner3) (justbelow3c)}, draw,fill=red!20] (outer3) {};
    \node[fit={(tech) (inner4) (justbelow4c)}, draw,fill=red!20] (outer4) {};
    \end{scope}
    \path (outer1) -- (outer2) node[pos=0.45,my arrow]{}
    (outer2) -- (outer3) node[pos=0.45,my arrow]{}
    (outer4) -- (outer3) node[pos=0.45,my arrow,shape border rotate=180]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there other ways to make the all red outer boxes have the same height? with this `\node[fit={(tech) (inner4) (justbelow4b)}, draw,fill=red!20] (outer4) {};` leaves me with uneven boxes. It's an issue when the text inside white boxes spans various lines.

Comment: Is there away to increase the vertical separation between red box title and the box below?

Comment: @SalJr I already show you want to do in `\node[fit={(lab) (inner1) (justbelow4c.south-|inner1.south)}, draw,fill=red!20] (outer1) {};` Here I add "fake" node `(justbelow4c.south-|inner1.south)` to the fit which is as low as the bottom of `justbelow4c`, which in my answer is (together with two other nodes) the lowest node. So as long as you do something analogous for your code, you will be fine. There are alternatives, which are however a bit more involved. And one way to move the labels up is to use `yshift`: `label={[name=cal,yshift=4pt]Calibration \& alignment`.

Comment: Yes. it was a matter of which element I do `.south-|innerx.south` on, great point.